# Efficient (Fast) Binary Tree in Fortran

Tags: performance, fortran, binary-tree, fortran90

I am using the procedure in the following code (that I took from [here](http://www.fortran.com/fortran_storenew/Html/Info/books/gd3_c08.html)) to a program that I am trying to make run as fast as possible. The procedure is, however, very slow since it is probably optimized for pedagogical purposes not speed.

```
program tree_sort
! Sorts a file of integers by building a
! tree, sorted in infix order.
! This sort has expected behavior n log n,
! but worst case (input is sorted) n ** 2.

   implicit none
   type node
      integer :: value
      type (node), pointer :: left, right
   end type node

   type (node), pointer :: t  ! A tree
   integer :: number, ios

   nullify (t)  ! Start with empty tree
   do
      read (*, *, iostat = ios) number
      if (ios < 0) exit
      call insert (t, number) ! Put next number in tree
   end do
   ! Print nodes of tree in infix order
   call print_tree (t)

contains

   recursive subroutine insert (t, number)

      type (node), pointer :: t  ! A tree
      integer, intent (in) :: number

      ! If (sub)tree is empty, put number at root
      if (.not. associated (t)) then
         allocate (t)
         t % value = number
         nullify (t % left)
         nullify (t % right)
      ! Otherwise, insert into correct subtree
      else if (number < t % value) then
         call insert (t % left, number)
      else
         call insert (t % right, number)
      end if

   end subroutine insert

   recursive subroutine print_tree (t)
   ! Print tree in infix order

      type (node), pointer :: t  ! A tree

      if (associated (t)) then
         call print_tree (t % left)
         print *, t % value
         call print_tree (t % right)
      end if

   end subroutine print_tree

end program tree_sort
```

Is there any way to speed it up? I am using the procedure to sequentially add elements to a vector without adding repeated ones (so I changed the `else` in the `insert` subroutine to `else if (number > t % value) then`. Other than that, instead of printing I store the values in a global variable.

**Edit:**

Here is the actual code:

```
MODULE MOD_PARAMETERS

USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
IMPLICIT NONE
SAVE

INTEGER(INT32), PARAMETER :: d     = 10    ! number of dimensions
INTEGER(INT32), PARAMETER :: L_0   = 5     ! after this adaptive grid kicks in, for L <= L_0 usual sparse grid
INTEGER(INT32), PARAMETER :: L_max = 5     ! maximum level
INTEGER(INT32), PARAMETER :: bound = 1     ! 0 -> for f = 0 at boundary
                                           ! 1 -> adding grid points at boundary
                                           ! 2 -> extrapolating close to boundary

INTEGER(INT32), PARAMETER :: testing_sample = 10**4
INTEGER(INT32), PARAMETER :: error_sample = 10**2

REAL(REAL64), PARAMETER :: eps = 0.001D0   ! epsilon for adaptive grid

TYPE NODE
  INTEGER :: value
  TYPE (NODE), POINTER :: left, right
END TYPE NODE

INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: tree_vector
INTEGER(INT32) :: iii

END MODULE MOD_PARAMETERS

SUBROUTINE FF(x,output)

    USE MOD_PARAMETERS
    IMPLICIT NONE

    REAL(REAL64), DIMENSION(d), INTENT(IN)  :: x
    REAL(REAL64)              , INTENT(OUT) :: output

    output = 1.0D0/(ABS(0.5D0-SUM(x(:)**4.0D0))+0.1D0)

END SUBROUTINE

SUBROUTINE XX(n,L,i,output)

    USE MOD_PARAMETERS
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER(INT32)              , INTENT(IN)  :: n
    INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(n), INTENT(IN)  :: L, i
    REAL(REAL64),   DIMENSION(n), INTENT(OUT) :: output

    INTEGER(INT32) :: j

    DO j = 1,n
        IF ((bound .EQ. 0) .OR. (bound .EQ. 2)) THEN
            output(j) = REAL(i(j),REAL64)/REAL(2**L(j),REAL64)
        ELSEIF (bound .EQ. 1) THEN
            output(j) = REAL(i(j),REAL64)/REAL(2**MAX(L(j)-1,1),REAL64)
        ENDIF
    ENDDO

END SUBROUTINE

SUBROUTINE XX_INV(L,x,output)

    USE MOD_PARAMETERS
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(d), INTENT(IN)  :: L
    REAL(REAL64),   DIMENSION(d), INTENT(IN)  :: x
    INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(d), INTENT(OUT) :: output

    INTEGER(INT32) :: j

    DO j = 1,d
        IF ((bound .EQ. 0) .OR. (bound .EQ. 2)) THEN
            output(j) = 2*FLOOR(x(j)*REAL(2**(L(j)-1),REAL64))+1
        ELSEIF (bound .EQ. 1) THEN
            IF (L(j) .EQ. 2) THEN
                IF (x(j) .LT. 0.5D0) THEN
                    output(j) = 0
                ELSE
                    output(j) = 2
                ENDIF
            ELSE
                output(j) = 2*FLOOR(x(j)*(REAL(2**MAX(L(j)-2,0),REAL64)))+1
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ENDDO

END SUBROUTINE

SUBROUTINE BASE(x,L,i,output)

    USE MOD_PARAMETERS
    IMPLICIT NONE

    REAL(REAL64),   INTENT(IN)  :: x
    INTEGER(INT32), INTENT(IN)  :: L,i
    REAL(REAL64),   INTENT(OUT) :: output

    IF (bound .EQ. 0) THEN
        output = MAX((1.0D0-ABS(x*REAL(2**L,REAL64)-REAL(i,REAL64))),0.0D0)
    ELSEIF (bound .EQ. 1) THEN
        IF ((L .EQ. 1) .AND. (i .EQ. 1)) THEN
            output = 1.0D0
        ELSEIF ((L .EQ. 2) .AND. (i .EQ. 0)) THEN
            output = MAX(1.0D0-2.0D0*x,0.0D0)
        ELSEIF ((L .EQ. 2) .AND. (i .EQ. 2)) THEN
            output = MAX(2.0D0*x-1.0D0,0.0D0)
        ELSE
            output = MAX((1.0D0-ABS(x*REAL(2**(L-1),REAL64)-REAL(i,REAL64))),0.0D0)
        ENDIF
    ELSEIF (bound .EQ. 2) THEN
        IF ((L .EQ. 1) .AND. (i .EQ. 1)) THEN
            output = 1.0D0
        ELSEIF ((L .GT. 1) .AND. (i .EQ. 1)) THEN
            output = MAX(2.0D0-REAL(2**L,REAL64)*x,0.0D0)
        ELSEIF ((L .GT. 1) .AND. (i .EQ. (2**L)-1)) THEN
            output = MAX(REAL(2**L,REAL64)*x+REAL(1-i,REAL64),0.0D0)
        ELSE
            output = MAX((1.0D0-ABS(x*REAL(2**L,REAL64)-REAL(i,REAL64))),0.0D0)
        ENDIF
    ENDIF

END SUBROUTINE

PROGRAM MAIN

USE MOD_PARAMETERS
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(d,d)                :: ident
REAL(REAL64),   DIMENSION(1)                  :: x1
REAL(REAL64),   DIMENSION(d)                  :: xd
INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(2*d)                :: temp
INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(:,:),   ALLOCATABLE :: grid_index, temp_grid_index, grid_index_new, J_index, &
                                                 adj_list, temp_adj_list
INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(:),     ALLOCATABLE :: to_do, to_do_new, to_add_ind
REAL(REAL64),   DIMENSION(:),     ALLOCATABLE :: coeff, temp_coeff, J_coeff

REAL(REAL64)  :: temp_min, temp_max, V, T, B, F
INTEGER(INT32) :: i, k, k1, k2, h, j, L, n, dd, dsize, count, count1, count2, count3, flag, &
                  first, repeated, add, ind, adj_list_ind


INTEGER(INT32) :: time1, time2, time3, time4, clock_rate, clock_max

INTEGER(INT32), DIMENSION(d) :: LL, ii

REAL(REAL64), DIMENSION(error_sample,d) :: sample_x
REAL(REAL64), DIMENSION(error_sample)   :: sample_e, interp1
REAL(REAL64)                            :: max_error, L2_error

REAL(REAL64), DIMENSION(testing_sample,d) :: x_rand
REAL(REAL64), DIMENSION(testing_sample)   :: interp2

TYPE(NODE), POINTER :: tree

! ============================================================================
! EXECUTABLE
! ============================================================================

ident = 0
DO i = 1,d
    ident(i,i) = 1
ENDDO

! Initial grid point
dsize = 1
ALLOCATE(grid_index(dsize,2*d),grid_index_new(dsize,2*d),adj_list(dsize,2*d))
grid_index(1,:) = 1
grid_index_new  = grid_index
adj_list        = 0

ALLOCATE(coeff(0:dsize))
coeff(0) = 0.0D0
xd = 0.5D0
CALL FF(xd,coeff(1))

L = 1
n = SIZE(grid_index_new,1)
ALLOCATE(J_index(n*2*d,2*d))
ALLOCATE(J_coeff(n*2*d))
ALLOCATE(to_add_ind(1))
to_add_ind = 1

CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(sample_x)
sample_e = 0.0D0

CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time1,clock_rate,clock_max)

DO WHILE (L .LT. L_max)

    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time3,clock_rate,clock_max)
    L       = L+1
    n       = SIZE(grid_index_new,1)
    count   = 0
    first   = 1
    DEALLOCATE(J_index,J_coeff)
    ALLOCATE(J_index(n*2*d,2*d))
    ALLOCATE(J_coeff(n*2*d))
    J_index = 0
    J_coeff = 0.0D0
    DO k = 1,n
        adj_list_ind = 0
        DO i = 1,d
            DO j = 1,2
                IF ((bound .EQ. 0) .OR. (bound .EQ. 2)) THEN
                    temp = grid_index_new(k,:)+(/ident(i,:),ident(i,:)*(grid_index_new(k,d+i)-(-1)**j)/)
                ELSEIF (bound .EQ. 1) THEN
                    IF (grid_index_new(k,i) .EQ. 1) THEN
                        temp = grid_index_new(k,:)+(/ident(i,:),ident(i,:)*(-(-1)**j)/)
                    ELSE
                        temp = grid_index_new(k,:)+(/ident(i,:),ident(i,:)*(grid_index_new(k,d+i)-(-1)**j)/)
                    ENDIF
                ENDIF
                CALL XX(d,temp(1:d),temp(d+1:2*d),xd)
                temp_min = MINVAL(xd)
                temp_max = MAXVAL(xd)
                IF ((temp_min .GE. 0.0D0) .AND. (temp_max .LE. 1.0D0)) THEN
                    IF (first .EQ. 1) THEN
                        first = 0
                        count = count+1
                        J_index(count,:) = temp
                        V = 0.0D0
                        DO k1 = 1,SIZE(grid_index,1)
                            T = 1.0D0
                            DO k2 = 1,d
                                CALL XX(1,temp(k2),temp(d+k2),x1)
                                CALL BASE(x1(1),grid_index(k1,k2),grid_index(k1,k2+d),B)
                                T = T*B
                            ENDDO
                            V = V+coeff(k1)*T
                        ENDDO
                        CALL FF(xd,F)
                        J_coeff(count) = F-V
                        adj_list(to_add_ind(k),adj_list_ind+1) = dsize+count
                        adj_list_ind = adj_list_ind+1
                    ELSE
                        repeated = 0
                        DO h = 1,count
                            IF (SUM(ABS(J_index(h,:)-temp)) .EQ. 0) THEN
                                repeated = 1
                                adj_list(to_add_ind(k),adj_list_ind+1) = dsize+h
                                adj_list_ind = adj_list_ind+1
                            ENDIF
                        ENDDO
                        IF (repeated .EQ. 0) THEN
                            count = count+1
                            J_index(count,:) = temp
                            V = 0.0D0
                            DO k1 = 1,SIZE(grid_index,1)
                                T = 1.0D0
                                DO k2 = 1,d
                                    CALL XX(1,temp(k2),temp(d+k2),x1)
                                    CALL BASE(x1(1),grid_index(k1,k2),grid_index(k1,k2+d),B)
                                    T = T*B
                                ENDDO
                                V = V+coeff(k1)*T
                            ENDDO
                            CALL FF(xd,F)
                            J_coeff(count) = F-V
                            adj_list(to_add_ind(k),adj_list_ind+1) = dsize+count
                            adj_list_ind = adj_list_ind+1
                        ENDIF
                    ENDIF
                ENDIF
            ENDDO
        ENDDO
    ENDDO

    ALLOCATE(temp_grid_index(dsize,2*d))
    ALLOCATE(temp_coeff(dsize))
    temp_grid_index = grid_index
    temp_coeff      = coeff
    DEALLOCATE(grid_index,coeff)
    ALLOCATE(grid_index(dsize+count,2*d))
    ALLOCATE(coeff(0:dsize+count))
    grid_index(1:dsize,:) = temp_grid_index
    coeff(0:dsize)        = temp_coeff
    DEALLOCATE(temp_grid_index,temp_coeff)
    grid_index(dsize+1:dsize+count,:) = J_index(1:count,:)
    coeff(dsize+1:dsize+count)        = J_coeff(1:count)

    IF (L .LT. L_max) THEN ! put this after error threshhold when implemented
        ALLOCATE(temp_adj_list(dsize,2*d))
        temp_adj_list = adj_list
        DEALLOCATE(adj_list)
        ALLOCATE(adj_list(dsize+count,2*d))
        adj_list            = 0
        adj_list(1:dsize,:) = temp_adj_list
        DEALLOCATE(temp_adj_list)
    ENDIF

    dsize = dsize + count

    IF (L .LE. L_0) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(grid_index_new)
        ALLOCATE(grid_index_new(count,2*d))
        grid_index_new = J_index(1:count,:)
        DEALLOCATE(to_add_ind)
        ALLOCATE(to_add_ind(count))
        to_add_ind = dsize-count + (/ (h,h=1,count) /)
    ELSE
        DEALLOCATE(to_add_ind)
        ALLOCATE(to_add_ind(count))
        add = 0
        to_add_ind = 0
        DO h = 1,count
            IF (ABS(J_coeff(h)) .GT. eps) THEN
                add = add + 1
                J_index(add,:) = J_index(h,:)
                to_add_ind(add) = dsize-count+h
            ENDIF
        ENDDO
        DEALLOCATE(grid_index_new)
        ALLOCATE(grid_index_new(add,2*d))
        grid_index_new = J_index(1:add,:)
    ENDIF

    DO i = 1,error_sample
        V = 0.0D0
        DO k1 = 1,SIZE(grid_index,1)
            T = 1.0D0
            DO k2 = 1,d
                CALL BASE(sample_x(i,k2),grid_index(k1,k2),grid_index(k1,k2+d),B)
                T = T*B
            ENDDO
            V = V+coeff(k1)*T
        ENDDO
        CALL FF(sample_x(i,:),F)
        sample_e(i) = F-V
        interp1(i)  = V
    ENDDO

    max_error = MAXVAL(ABS(sample_e))
    L2_error  = (SUM(sample_e**2.0D0)/REAL(error_sample,REAL64))**0.5D0

    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time4,clock_rate,clock_max)
    WRITE(*,'(A,I5,A,F10.5,A,I8,A,F15.10,A,F15.10)') ' level = ', L,&
        '      time = ',REAL(time4-time3,REAL64)/REAL(clock_rate,REAL64),&
        '    grid points = ',SIZE(grid_index,1),&
        '    max error = ',max_error,&
        '    L2 error = ',L2_error

ENDDO

!PRINT *, ' '
!PRINT *, ' '
!PRINT *, ' '
!DO i = 1,SIZE(adj_list,1)
!    PRINT *, i, adj_list(i,:)
!ENDDO
!PRINT *, ' '
!PRINT *, ' '
!PRINT *, ' '
!DO i = 1,dsize
!    PRINT *, i, grid_index(i,:), coeff(i)
!ENDDO
!PRINT *, ' '
!PRINT *, ' '
!PRINT *, ' '

ALLOCATE (to_do(dsize),to_do_new(dsize),tree_vector(dsize))

CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time2,clock_rate,clock_max)
PRINT *, ' '
WRITE(*,'(A,F10.5)') '    total time for setup = ', REAL(time2-time1,REAL64)/REAL(clock_rate,REAL64)

! ============================================================================
!  Compute interpolated values:
! ============================================================================

IF (testing_sample .EQ. error_sample) THEN
!    x_rand = sample_x
ELSE
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(x_rand)
ENDIF

count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0

CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time1,clock_rate,clock_max)
DO i = 1,testing_sample

    V = 0.0D0
    to_do     = 0
    to_do(1)  = 1
    to_do_new = 0
    k = 1
    DO L = 1,L_max

        NULLIFY (tree)
        tree_vector = 0

        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time3,clock_rate,clock_max)
        DO j = 1,k
            ind = to_do(j)
            T = 1.0D0
            DO dd = 1,d
                CALL BASE(x_rand(i,dd),grid_index(ind,dd),grid_index(ind,d+dd),B)
                T = T*B
            ENDDO
            V = V + coeff(ind)*T
        ENDDO
        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time4,clock_rate,clock_max)
        count1 = count1 + time4-time3

        IF (L .LT. L_max) THEN
            n = k
            k = 0

            DO j = 1,n
                IF (adj_list(to_do(j),1) .GT. 0) THEN
                    DO h = 1,2*d

                        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time3,clock_rate,clock_max)
                        LL = grid_index(adj_list(to_do(j),h),1:d)
                        ii = grid_index(adj_list(to_do(j),h),d+1:2*d)
                        flag = 0
                        k1 = 1
                        DO WHILE ((flag .EQ. 0) .AND. (k1 .LE. d))
                            IF ((bound .EQ. 0) .OR. (bound .EQ. 2)) THEN
                                k2 = 2*FLOOR(x_rand(i,k1)*REAL(2**(LL(k1)-1),REAL64))+1
                            ELSEIF (bound .EQ. 1) THEN
                                IF (LL(k1) .EQ. 2) THEN
                                    IF (x_rand(i,k1) .LT. 0.5D0) THEN
                                        k2 = 0
                                    ELSE
                                        k2 = 2
                                    ENDIF
                                ELSE
                                    k2 = 2*FLOOR(x_rand(i,k1)*(REAL(2**MAX(LL(k1)-2,0),REAL64)))+1
                                ENDIF
                            ENDIF
                            IF (k2 .NE. ii(k1)) THEN
                                flag = 1
                            ENDIF
                            k1 = k1 +1
                        ENDDO
                        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time4,clock_rate,clock_max)
                        count2 = count2 + time4-time3

!                        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time3,clock_rate,clock_max)
                        IF (flag .EQ. 0) THEN
                            !IF (MINVAL(ABS(to_do_new(1:MAX(k,1))-adj_list(to_do(j),h))) .GT. 0) THEN
                                to_do_new(k+1) = adj_list(to_do(j),h)
                                k = k+1
                                CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time3,clock_rate,clock_max)
                                CALL INSERT(tree,to_do_new(k))
                                CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time4,clock_rate,clock_max)
                                count3 = count3 + time4-time3
                            !ENDIF
                        ENDIF
!                        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time4,clock_rate,clock_max)
!                        count3 = count3 + time4-time3
                    ENDDO
                ENDIF
            ENDDO

            CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time3,clock_rate,clock_max)
            iii = 0
            CALL PRINT_TREE(tree)
            to_do = tree_vector
            CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time4,clock_rate,clock_max)
            count3 = count3 + time4-time3

            !to_do = to_do_new
            to_do_new = 0
        ENDIF

    ENDDO
    interp2(i) = V
ENDDO

CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK (time2,clock_rate,clock_max)

PRINT *, ' '
WRITE(*,'(A,F10.5,A,I10)') '  time for interpolation = ', REAL(time2-time1,REAL64)/REAL(clock_rate,REAL64),&
                           '    points = ', testing_sample
PRINT *, ' '
WRITE(*,'(A,F10.5)') '           time for base = ', REAL(count1,REAL64)/REAL(clock_rate,REAL64)

PRINT *, ' '
WRITE(*,'(A,F10.5)') '          time for x_inv = ', REAL(count2,REAL64)/REAL(clock_rate,REAL64)

PRINT *, ' '
WRITE(*,'(A,F10.5)') '       time for repeated = ', REAL(count3,REAL64)/REAL(clock_rate,REAL64)

!PRINT *, ' '
!WRITE(*,'(A,F20.15)') '                   check = ', MAXVAL(ABS(interp2-interp1))

DEALLOCATE(grid_index,grid_index_new,J_index,coeff,J_coeff,adj_list,to_do,to_do_new,to_add_ind,tree_vector)

CONTAINS

RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE INSERT(tree,number)

    TYPE(NODE), POINTER :: tree
    INTEGER(INT32),  INTENT(IN) :: number

    IF (.NOT. ASSOCIATED(tree)) THEN
        ALLOCATE(tree)
        tree%value = number
        NULLIFY(tree%left)
        NULLIFY(tree%right)
    ELSEIF (number .LT. tree%value) THEN
        CALL INSERT (tree%left,number)
    ELSEIF (number .GT. tree%value) THEN
        CALL INSERT(tree%right,number)
    ENDIF

END SUBROUTINE INSERT

RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE PRINT_TREE(tree)

    TYPE (NODE), POINTER :: tree

    IF (ASSOCIATED(tree)) THEN
        CALL PRINT_TREE(tree%left)
        iii = iii+1
        tree_vector(iii) = tree%value
        CALL PRINT_TREE (tree%right)
    END IF

END SUBROUTINE PRINT_TREE

END PROGRAM
```

I am using optimization `O3` but otherwise no flags. In my computer the `time for repeated` (which is where I am using the binary tree) is 18.3 seconds, whereas if I use an alternative method that is commented in the version (with `MINVAL`) it only takes 3.6 seconds.

Comment: What size tree are we talking about?

Comment: About 10000 elements.

Comment: It might be faster to allocate a batch of `node` types at once, rather than individually allocating each insert. Insert then pulls from that batch. I don't have a good implementation of this, though.

Comment: 10,000 elements doesn't sound too bad. I've used your code, compiled it with `gfortran` v5.4, and had it run over 10,000 elements. It took just over half a second, but when I redirected the output to a file, rather than stdout, it was down to 30ms. Looks to me that the `print` statement in the `print_tree` subroutine will be your bottleneck ;)

Comment: Just noticed that you write that you don't print the statements. Can you please show us **your** code, because, as I pointed out before, the actual populating of the tree is really fast, and I want to see how you transfer the values into a global variable.

Comment: @chw21 I suspect you are right. I put the relevant part of the actual in the question.

Comment: This version is still fast. Since `vector1` is an array all in memory, you can split the generation of `vector1` and its insertion into `tree` into separate loops. Put a `print` statement between those two loops to see whether it's the generation of `vector1` that's slowing things down.

Comment: I am sorry, but if something is too slow you must give us the actual code that is slow. There is simply no other way, how could it be? Maybe you have a bug on line 42 in file xyz.f90, who knows? It is good to make profiling to identify the real botlenecks first. I had excellent results with Oracle Studio Analyzer (even for programs compiled with other compilers). Don't forget to tell us the compiler flags you are using, especially the level of optimizations.

Comment: One more thing: Since your data is already in a 1d array, and you want it to be in another 1d array, why not ignore the whole binary search tree and use a quicksort routine?

Comment: I apologize, I am traveling today but will post the entire code as soon as I can.

Comment: @VladimirF, sorry for the delay but I added the entire code now.

Comment: OK.. But why you don't just call quicksort? Even if an algorithm has good asymptotic complexity O(something), it can still be too slow due to  a large constant factor. That probably happens here.